# What should I say when I couldn't meet an intervewer?

Tags: expressions

I had an interview. I expected to meet some interviewer who I was communicating with online, yet he wasn't there during the interview.

I want to tell him 'online' that "I was hoping to meet you" in a formal and clever way. A clever English famous quote would be appreciated!

Share your awesome ideas!

Comment: Better to say nothing at all: the process is probably compartmentalized, and any further communication might serve to only annoy a busy person.

Answer (score 0):

Based loosely on the [Mark Twain misquote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Mark_Twain), "The reports of my death are greatly exaggerated," you could write, "Sorry the reports of our meeting in person were greatly exaggerated."

However, bringing the subject up is risky since you do not know why the hiring process left out the obvious interviewer. The formal choice is the one that leaves out referring to your justifiable disappointment. Simply say a few things you liked in those you actually met, along with an item or two that you learned and you liked.